# Here Routing API without HTML

Tags: here-api

I would like to ask you if it is possible to disable the html tags for the Routing API response.

For example:

```
Go to the <span class="company">U</span> station 
<span class="station">U Pankstr. (Berlin)</span> 
and take the <span class="transit">rail</span> 
<span class="line">U8</span> towards
```

is the response. I would like to have this as a result:

```
Go to the U station 
U Pankstr. (Berlin)
and take the rail
U8 towards
```

My api call is like the example api call from here: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-a-simple-route.html

It would be great if I could disable the html tags.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `instructionFormat` to `text` you get the instructions without the html tags. Example:

`https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4
&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45
&instructionFormat=text
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled`